# Ubuntu latest screen sharing and Screen turning yellow issue

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I have installed latest `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`. I am using extended screen with my laptop (MSI GF65 Thin). Issue is that when I attach extended screen it's turn all yellow. To solve this issue I enabled `WayLandEnable=true` in

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

But know I am not able to share my screen (e.g in google meet and slack huddle etc). To do that I have to turn `WayLandEnable=false` and reboot system and again extended screen turn yellow.

Comment: Key detail mising make and model of video card and what driver you have used.